# Why does my Acer AC713 beep for about two seconds and does not start up?

Tags: windows-xp

I have an Acer AC713 computer. When I'm starting my computer a beep sound for about 2 seconds is coming from my cpu itself. I'm seeing an orange light only in my monitor.

What's the problem in my computer?

Comment: Take it to a local expert. These problems are very difficult to solve via the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a problem with the memory, maybe bad or not seated correctly.  Or could be a problem with the video card, bad or not seated.  Could be many things but that'd be my first intuition.

The manual for your computer or the motherboard may give you information on how to interpret beeps.

Comment: A beep at startup means one of the two above mentioned malfunctions.

Answer (score 0):

Run [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) to diagnose any memory problems.  This could cause a failure to boot to Windows and a failure to install Windows correctly.  Test all sticks together for multiple passes.  If you receive ANY errors, begin testing individual sticks to determine the culprit.  Remove any stick that receives an error!

Comment: Doesn't really help if the machine doesn't start up though.

Comment: Valid point.  I'd start reseating RAM and/or replacing it with known-working units.